# Reshape arbitrary length vector into square matrix with padding in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an arbitrary length vector, and I want to reshape it into a square matrix, something like:

```
np.arange(6).reshape((3, 3))

[1,2,x]   [1,2,3]    
[3,4,x]   [4,5,6]
[5,6,x]   [x,x,x]
```

The `x` can be horizontally and/or vertically placed.

Obviously `reshape` function will only allow parameter like (3,2) in the above example. Is there a way to produce effect of squared shaped matrix.Thanks.

Comment: What defines the shape of the square ? I can fit this into 7x7 too

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But each of the dimension of the matrix would be close to the square root of the length of the vector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to pad the array, either before or after reshape.

For example, using the `resize` method to add the needed 0s:

```
In [409]: x=np.arange(6)
In [410]: x.resize(3*3)
In [411]: x.shape
Out[411]: (9,)
In [412]: x.reshape(3,3)
Out[412]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

The `np.resize` replicates values.  `np.pad` is also handy for adding 0s, though it might overkill.

With `np.arange(6)` we can pad before or after reshape.  With `np.arange(5)` we have to stick with before, because the padding will be irregular.

```
In [409]: x=np.arange(6)
In [410]: x.resize(3*3)
In [411]: x.shape
Out[411]: (9,)
In [412]: x.reshape(3,3)
Out[412]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

In any case there isn't one function that does all of this in one call - at least not that I know of.  This isn't a common enough operation.

Answer (score 10):

You can define the closest square and then carry the array to it and reshape

```
import numpy as np
n = np.random.randint(10, 200)
a = np.arange(n)
ns = np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)).astype(int)
s = np.zeros(ns**2)
s[:a.size] = a
s = s.reshape(ns,ns)
```